# Why Prometheus does not raise error on invisible metric?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks, prometheus-alertmanager

We have a custom metric that gets exported only upon some error condition in app

Alert rule use that custom metric that gets registered with rule manager of Prometheus

Why Prometheus does not raise error, when this metric name is queried? Despite the metric is not available in Prometheus yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems correct that the absence of a signal is not treated as an error.

However, it can cause problems with dashboards and alerting.

See this presentation by one of Prometheus' creators: [Best Practices & Beastly Pitfalls](https://promcon.io/2017-munich/slides/best-practices-and-beastly-pitfalls.pdf)

Comment: Alert rule with invisible metric is being hooked with Prometheus successfully.

Comment: By "hooked" do you mean the alert is registered? This is expected. Or, do you mean the alert fires? This is unexpected. It would be helpful if you included details of what you're doing and observing in your question.

Comment: yes the alert is registered. We are observing "missing series" issue, because metric name is not yet instrumented in the target, before alert is registered with that metric.

Comment: Please have a look at the deck I included in my answer (see slide #10+) and [Existential issues with metrics](https://www.robustperception.io/existential-issues-with-metrics)